# mysqlに挿入すると文字化けする

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

htmlsimpledomでスクレイピングによって要素を取得し、
PDOで文字列をmysqlにinsertすると下記のように文字化けします。

```
&#12486;&#12451;&#12501;&#12449;&#12540;&#12523; &#38651;&#27671;&#12465;&#12488;&#12523; &#12300;&#12450;&#12503;&#12524;&#12471;&#12450; &#12503;&#12521;&#12473;&#12301; &#12467;&#12531;&#12497;&#12463;&#12488;&#12514;&#12487;&#12523; &#12459;&#12501;&#12455;&#12458;&#12524; 0.8L BF805170
```

どのように改善すべきでしょうか。
詳しい方、いらっしゃいましたら、ご教示ください。よろしくお願い致します。

文字化け対策としては、以下のように設定していますが、ダメなようです。

```
<?php
mb_language('ja');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');   
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO(DSN, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        $stmt = $dbh -> query("SET NAMES utf8;");
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
```

挿入している要素はvar_dumpで確認すると(string)になっているので、文字列で間違い無いです。

Comment: 「ティファール 電気ケトル 「アプレシア プラス」 コンパクトモデル カフェオレ 0.8L BF805170」という文字列がhtmlencodeされているようです。心当たり有りますでしょうか。

Comment: はい、amazonの商品情報をスクレイピングしていたので、商品タイトルだと思います。。ただ、id="brand"で指定されているメーカーの名前も全く同じように取得しているのですが、こちらは正常にinsertされています。。

Comment: htmlspecialchars_decodeの関数も試してみましたが、ダメなようです。。

Comment: 「PDOで文字列をmysqlにinsertすると下記のように文字化け」と断定されていますが、元データをHTMLから取得したのであれば、元のデータ自体が`&#12486;`のような文字実体参照で構成されているのではありませんか。試しにAmazonのページを幾つか覗いてみましたが、文字実体参照はかなり多用されていました。(ブラウザは文字実体参照を普通に文字コードとして解釈してしまうので、ソースを見ないとわかりません。)

Answer (score 2):

&#12486;は文字化けではなくHTMLで使われる「数値文字参照」という文字の指定方法です。

試してないですが、[html_entity_decode](http://php.benscom.com/manual/ja/function.html-entity-decode.php)で数値文字参照を元に戻せるようです。

---

ところで、PHP+MySQLにおいてデータベースの文字エンコーディングを指定する場合、SET NAMESを使用するのは好ましくありません。

どのように指定したらよいかは http://blog.tokumaru.org/2011/08/pdo.html が参考になります